# cmake-gui show blank except source code directory and binaries directory

Tags: user-interface, cmake

After installing cmake-3.8.1-win64-x64 I got this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02hH2.png)

So what can I do with this? Thanks.

Comment: It is you who should fill these fields.

Answer (score 0):

cmake-gui does not help you create cmake configuration files, it parses these files to generate and configure projects.

In your source code directory, you should have a CMakeLists.txt file which defines the rules for CMAKE to configure your problem.  That directory should be entered into the first box.

Next, you get to decide where to build the binaries.  We could do it in the source directory, but the generated artifacts could pollute what is already there.  "Cleaning" the build by deleting all of those artifacts while keeping the original sources is tedious at best, so it's a good idea to make an empty directory and use that as your binaries path.

Once you have those fields entered, you should be able to "Generate" or "Configure" your project.  If you need help creating a CMakeLists.txt file (that's really the complicated part), then check out their [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/).

Comment: Sloved it now, it seems that I overlaped the Configuration zone with Output zone sometime before, it is really weired that the modification on GUI preserves after re-installation. Anyway, Thank your!

Comment: That's because when you "configure" cmake, it creates a cache in the binary directory.  This cache is not "owned" by cmake, and so re-installing does not delete the cache.  When you run it again, the new installation will just read the same cache from the same binary directory.  To reset the cache, just delete all of the contents from the binary directory.